# Ejecutar codigo de pyqt en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt5

como puedo ejecutar este codigo? quiero usar pyqt, hacer ventanas, poner botones pero no obtengo nada, estoy siguiendo este tutorial:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('QHBoxLayout')
layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Left'))
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Center'))
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Right'))
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

para ejecutar use: python3 hello.py

debo usar si o si qtcreator?

Comment: ¿que obtienes al ejecutar el comando en la consola?

Comment: no obtengo nada. simplemente no hace nada